# How to find number of occurrences of a table of key words in a column of strings in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Column A, I have a list of key words separated by rows, such as

```
key1
key2
key3
key4
```

They are all string values -- literally `"key1"`, `"key2"`, etc.

In Column B, I have a mix of words that could be key words in Column A, each word separated by rows, such as

```
word1
word2
key2
word3
key3
word1
word4
key3
word5
key1
word3
```

---

Question:

How do I count the number of occurrences of key words from Column A in Column B in one formula?

If a method happens to involve generating an array of occurred key words in Column B, could the answer explain how to do that too please? Thanks

Comment: countif() would be a possibility.

Comment: @SolarMike: Would you be able to explain what is allowed in the criterion of `countif`? I only know simple `=`, `<>` type of comparisons. I guess that can be combined with `arrayformula(iferror(match(...` in this case. But not understanding how `countif` is what got me to ask the question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use FILTER:MATCH.

> FILTER(B1:B20,MATCH(B1:B20,A1:A4,0))

- match the COLUMN B to COLUMN A range. Then just use COUNTA in the filtered result.

[Counted Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A04A3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did this in Excel, just to show what may work:

So, first uses the criteria based on A1:A4,

Or you can use the second and define each separately as A1, A2 in separate cells.

[image]

The you could put "="&A1 or "<>"&A1 etc as needed. Most of these can be seen in the help entry for countif or you can try and see what works.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Sheets, one option is to use QUERY:

```
=query({B1:B},"select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 matches '"&textjoin("|",1,A1:A)&"' group by Col1",0)
```

We are using QUERY's *where...matches* operator together with TEXTJOIN to filter column B for those words found in column A, then *group by* to enable the occurrences of each to be counted.